# Difficult to read source code for some web pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I have been trying to find an explanation for this, but everywhere I looked doesn't seem to answer my question. Essentially, whenever I look at the "view page source" option on a webpage like Facebook or my school's home page (gvsu.edu), the source code is just a huge wall of text. As a result, I have a few questions:

Is this how it looks in the editor? If not, why is it formatted this way when I look at the source code?

Is there any way to decipher this code so I can see how it works?

Are there any advantages to formatting the code this way?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe move this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, chances are it's minified so it takes up less space. If you want to view the source looking good, go to the developer tools (usually `ctrl+shift+j`). You can also use the sources tab of Chrome's dev tools and click "Pretty Print" in the bottom left corner.

Comment: That's for  two purposes
1) Reduce source code file size by removing comments and Space.
2)It might act as a security sometimes ,not always only for noob users.

Comment: What browser are you using? On Safari and Google Chrome of Mac OS X it seems to be formatted fine. Of course, if you are using a command line (run, Terminal, etc) it will look like a glob of code that will need an external program to make neat if you copy it from there. From what I am guessing, it is to save space and make pages load faster. Think of it like a compressed file, a tar.gz or .zip. EDIT:  Keerthana Prabhakaran beat me to it!

Comment: Also the code what you see on the browser is mostly generated on the fly by some back-end scripting language according to your request.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this how it looks in the editor? If not, why is it formatted this way when I look at the source code?

no, usually programmers try to make code as readable as they can, this is a "minified" version of the code, it's done to make files smaller so people can receive it faster in their browsers.

> Is there any way to decipher this code so I can see how it works?

you can use some online tool to like [this](http://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/), you will have to format html, css and javascript individually.

> Are there any advantages to formatting the code this way?

already answered, but here I can add that usually you don't format the html/css/js that way, you have a tool that does that job for you like [gulp-htmlmin](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/gulp-htmlmin), [gulp uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify), [cssmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cssmin) or many others, and you work with a "development" version of the files, when you are done editing you run some scripts and they spit that minified version to you, so you can upload it to your server.